# Better practice of showing and hiding navigation bar, (having a button "View Cart"), hidden (css) or innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, css, innerhtml, hidden

I am having a navbar, which I want to show when an item is added to the cart. I tried using innerHtml, but it was not working so I did it with hiding using css property. I want to know which would be a better practice? And if innerHtml is a better practice then how can I do it correctly?
Using css:

```
.hidden{
    display: none !important;
}

<nav class=" navbar fixed-bottom  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-info " id="checkoutnav">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mx-2" id="popcart" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">
     View Cart
  </button>
</nav>

function hidecheckoutnav(){
    let checkoutnav = document.getElementById('checkoutnav');
    checkoutnav.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

Or using innerHtml (which did not work):

```
document.getElementById('nav').innerHTML ='<nav class=" navbar fixed-bottom  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-info " id="checkoutnav"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success mx-2" id="popcart" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">View Cart</button></nav>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just show/hide the navbar container is the best practice rather than innerHTML.

There is no append support without reparsing the whole innerHTML. This makes changing innerHTML directly very slow.

innerHTML does not provide validation and therefore we can potentially insert valid and broken HTML in the document and break it.

- The use of innerHTML very slow: The process of using innerHTML is much slower as its contents as slowly built, also already parsed contents and elements are also re-parsed which takes time.
- Preserves event handlers attached to any DOM elements: The event handlers do not get attached to the new elements created by setting innerHTML automatically. To do so one has to keep track of the event handlers and attach it to new elements manually. This may cause a memory leak on some browsers.
- Content is replaced everywhere: Either you add, append, delete or modify contents on a webpage using innerHTML, all contents is replaced, also all the DOM nodes inside that element are reparsed and recreated.
- Appending to innerHTML is not supported: Usually, += is used for appending in JavaScript. But on appending to an Html tag using innerHTML, the whole tag is re-parsed.
  Example:

```
<p id="geek">Geeks</p>
title = document.getElementById('#geek')

// The whole "geek" tag is reparsed
title.innerHTML += '<p> forGeeks </p>'
```

- Old content replaced issue: The old content is replaced even if object.innerHTML = object.innerHTML + ‘html’ is used instead of object.innerHTML += ‘html’. There is no way of appending without reparsing the whole innerHTML. Therefore, working with innerHTML becomes very slow. String concatenation just does not scale when dynamic DOM elements need to be created as the plus’ and quote openings and closings becomes difficult to track.
- Can break the document: There is no proper validation provided by innerHTML, so any valid HTML code can be used. This may break the document of JavaScript. Even broken HTML can be used, which may lead to unexpected problems.
- Can also be used for Cross-site Scripting(XSS): The fact that innerHTML can add text and elements to the webpage, can easily be used by malicious users to manipulate and display undesirable or harmful elements within other HTML element tags. Cross-site Scripting may also lead to loss, leak and change of sensitive information.